# Docker Swarm: How to handle persistent data (e.g. database)

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-volume, docker-swarm-mode

I have 3-node docker swarm mode cluster (1 manager and 2 workers).

Now I want to deploy a mongodb service to the cluster and I would like to store the database on a persistent storage that I've mounted under `/mnt/data`. So basically I want the service to use my mounted storage inside each containers `/db/data`.

How do I achieve this?

I made myself familiar with `docker service create --mount` but

- I am not sure if I should use a `volume` or a `bind-mount` ?
- if I choose `volume` how can I tell docker to store this volume on `/mnt/data`

To couple the mongodb services to a specific node (where the storage is mounted) I added a `label` to the corresponding node and start the docker service with a constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to bind mount the volume with mongodb data. follow the below steps on master server

1. docker volume create -d local --name mongodata
2. docker service create --network mongo \
    --mount type=volume,source=mongodata,target=/data/db \
    --constraint 'node.role == manager' \
    mongo:3.2

you can also look at setting up mongodb cluster in swarm to have the db running in HA mode. follow the below link
https://medium.com/@kalahari/running-a-mongodb-replica-set-on-docker-1-12-swarm-mode-step-by-step-a5f3ba07d06e